# Bootstrap Modal title not shown - ::before ::after

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

when I type `$('#MesageModal').modal('show');` , the modal's title has `::before` and `::after` selectors around it, made the title looks strange. Can someone tell me why this happened?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MessageModal" style="display: none">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use like **.modal-title:before{content: 'This is modal title';}**

Comment: This ::befor and ::after part is only for "clearing both" by using css         {display: table; content: " ";} this is not doing any effect for your modal-title. check your css for any modification for modal-title.

Comment: @PushkarAdhikari thanks!

Comment: can you add screenshot of the view that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MesageModal').modal('show');
```

It's should be

```
$('#MessageModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: it is just a typo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with c# mvc.net, I was loading an modal popup with:

```
<div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = user.UserId }, new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "mymodal", OnSuccess = "showModal" })
</div>
```

then I had mymodal div like this:

```
<div id="mymodal">

</div>
```

With a line between div tags, and my title was not showed. Neither the ':before' or ':after' sections

I just remove the middle line and my problem was solved, like this:

```
<div id="mymodal">
</div>
```